# Pandas DataFrame: group hourly and apply functions

Tags: python, pandas

I have some stock data in a pandas dataframe that looks like this (index=datetime)

```
                            ask      bid
datetime
2017-03-01 00:00:07.346  1.33145  1.33135
2017-03-01 00:00:07.498  1.33147  1.33134
2017-03-01 00:00:08.124  1.33147  1.33133
2017-03-01 00:00:08.659  1.33148  1.33134
2017-03-01 00:00:12.104  1.33146  1.33134
2017-03-01 00:00:12.858  1.33147  1.33134
2017-03-01 00:00:17.583  1.33148  1.33135
```

I would like to group this data into two hour chunks and add some new columns.

```
                    Open Ask, Close Ask, Max Ask, Open Bid, Max Bid, Close Bid   
 datetime
 2017-03-01 00:00
 2017-03-01 02:00
 ...
```

Where OpenAsk is the first Ask price in the 2 hour period, Close Ask is the last Ask price in the two hour period, etc.

How would I go about this? I think I can use resample, but im not sure how to find Open Ask, Close Ask, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick answer

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('2H')).agg(['first', 'last', 'max'])

                ask                        bid                  
              first     last      max    first     last      max
datetime                                                        
2017-03-01  1.33145  1.33148  1.33148  1.33135  1.33135  1.33135
```

---

With the formatting to produce your desired results

```
fs = dict(Open='first', Close='last', Max='max')
ag = dict(Ask=fs, Bid=fs)
gp = pd.TimeGrouper('2H')
d1 = df.rename(columns=str.capitalize).groupby(gp).agg(ag)
d1.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False, inplace=True)
d1.columns = d1.columns.map('{0[1]} {0[0]}'.format)
print(d1)

            Open Ask  Max Ask  Close Ask  Open Bid  Max Bid  Close Bid
datetime                                                              
2017-03-01   1.33145  1.33148    1.33148   1.33135  1.33135    1.33135
```